# Is there any possible way to programmatically load all images from a local workspace directory to a vite-react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, vite, image-gallery

I am trying to figure out a way for me to add some jpgs to my cats gallery. My layout includes images from one of three categories. I am using vite-react scaffold. I thought I could find a way to create one folder for each category, add all the jpgs in that folder, and then drum up some JSX to handle rendering. This is what I have so far. PS - the console is logging nothing - no errors or my attempt to confirm all the values were logging

```js
// import { useState } from 'react'
import * as allFloofs from './assets/floofs/floofs'

function App() {
  // const [images, setImages] = useState(false)
  for (var i = 0; i < allFloofs.length; i++) {
    let src = `${allFloofs[i]}`;
    console.log(allFloofs[i])
    let floof = new Image();
    floof.src = src;
    querySelector.image - container.appendChild(floof);
  }


  return ( 
<div className = "App" >
    <div className = "image-container" >
    <div> {
      /*  <Floofs/> 
          <Sleps/> 
          <Snyks/>  */
    } 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div >
  )
}

export default App
```

```css
.App {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.image-container div:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.image-container div:last-child {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.image img {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

:root {
  font-family: Inter, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color-scheme: light dark;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  background-color: #242424;
  font-synthesis: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #646cff;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

a:hover {
  color: #535bf2;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color 0.25s;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #646cff;
}

button:focus,
button:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
   :root {
    color: #213547;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: #747bff;
  }
  button {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/index.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>  F.I.R  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[dir layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEwp5.png)